# Correct implementation of many-to-many in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Newbie question, beware! I'd like to implement a basic many-to-many relationship in Rails and I'm trying to find out which approach is considered the most "rails way" of them. In a traditional non-ActiveRecord DB I'd just created two tables and a junction table and written a bunch of logic to make sure all three tables are taken in consideration when operations are performed on any of them.

This is my first time using an ORM and so I'm trying to find out if perhaps ActiveRecord somehow simplifies the process for you, perhaps by not requiring a junction table to be manually created.

Railscasts seems like a reputable source of Rails wisdom, are the two ways in this cast truly "Rails way" or can I do better? - http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

Comment: This seems pretty subjective, given that AFAIK there is no strict definition of a "Rails way" of doing things. FWIW, the second example in the Railscast link is how I was taught to do many-to-many in Rails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's basically two ways: `has_and_belongs_to_many` (`habtm`) and `has_many` with a :through option that points to another association. Both require join tables; the latter is what we call a join model, because you typically add more information to the join.

For example, consider an application with a User model who bookmarks Sites.  One way would be to implement it as a `habtm` relationship

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sites
end
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

user.sites << Site.find(...)
```

This modeling will also require creating the `sites_users` table, which necessarily will lack a primary key.

The problem with this is you're likely to want to store additional information on it, so you might as well go with a join model, in this case Bookmark:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :sites, :through => :bookmarks
end
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :users, :through => :bookmarks
  #edit: adding validation for requiring at least one bookmark
  validate_before_create :at_least_one_bookmark
  private
  def at_least_one_bookmark
    errors.add_to_base("requires at least one bookmark") unless bookmarks.count > 0
  end
end
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :site
end

user.bookmarks.create(:site => Site.find(...) )
```

The more common pattern is the join model approach for its versatility and better modelling, though `habtm`s are still used somewhat. They're just so two-dimensional that you really need to examine what you're doing and make sure there isn't some richer behavior that needs to be modelled as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response! On a related note, what's the best way of putting a foreign key constraint when using the join model approach (the 2nd solution)?

For example, let's say you should not be able to create a Site without an existing Bookmark associated with it.

Comment: You can add constraints at the database level using your migrations, then back them up with validations on the model. Edited example above to show the validation you'd want.

Answer (score 1):

Railscasts is the most reliable source of wisdom :) Rayan Bates teach a true "rails way" to solve problems in ruby on rails applications. You should definitely do it this way.

But if you want to learn more about associations then please follow this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, Rails makes this all pretty easy using either [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association-reference) or [has_many though](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association).

I wouldn't say that one is "more right" than the other, it just depends on what you need to do, specifically around how you need to manipulate the joined models. Deciding between them is discussed [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many).

(All those references are from the association doc already provided.)