# Rails rake db:seed Inserts nulls instead of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.1.5 and Rails 4.2.1 I'm trying to put some static database entries into a sqlite3 table via seeds.rb.  When I run rake db:seed, I get the correct number of rows inserted with appropriate timestamp columns, but the actual data column, name, is not being populated.  Name is being printed out inside the loop.

db/seed.rb

```
for g in ['Harmony', 'Melody', 'Technique', 'Soloing']
    Group.create(name: g)
    put(g)
end
```

app/models/group.rb:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name
    has_many :group2exercise
    has_many :exercises, through :group2exercise
end
```

sqlite3 (copying the create from SQLDB Browser)

```
CREATE TABLE "groups"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of `attribute_accessible` ? It's deprecated in Rails 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you remove the line

```
attr_accessor :name
```

By having `attr_accessor`, a new set of getter and setter methods are created, in this case overriding what Rails provided.

Comment: I've found a work around but I will go back and try the proposed solutions.  I *think* the problem was in the has_many statements.  I went back and setup the models using "rails g scaffold groups name:string", "rails g scaffold group2exercise group:integer exercise:integer" and I did not edit the model.

Comment: There is something quite wrong with your 'rails g' statements. If you suspect the has_many is the cause, remove it and try again.

Comment: Of course I deleted the bad project without thinking once I had the original problem solved. Working backwards from my now working project I believe you are right.  Both the attr_accessor and the has_many, through statements cause it to break.  The other has_many is ok, although it may not be complete.

Comment: More fundamentally, I used http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html which is a great resource for the different types of association.  My only complaint would be that the Ruby Cookbook gives firmer advice that if you are using has_one, you probably should merge your tables.  Still, this page does not provide the necessary context for a new person to understand which scaffolding commands to use, whether you need to put statements into migrate scripts to enforce the foreign key relationships, etc.

Comment: If you know of a simple tutorial or demo project that shows how to setup a many to many relationship, I would be grateful.

Comment: Using http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/ar-many_to_many.html, I have been able to add the has_many  statements.

Comment: @P.H. Here is a very old [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) and an [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322230/correct-implementation-of-many-to-many-in-ruby-on-rails)