# Rails - Seeding the database with nil instead of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created an app in Rails 4.2.3
I am trying to seed the database but after I do rake db:migrate I am getting nil values in the field of the database table. The only piece of code I have in my seeds.rb is:

```
    User.create![{username: "test", password_digest: "test"}]
```

In my schema.rb I have:

```
    create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string   "username"
      t.string   "password_digest"
      t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    end
```

My User model is:

```
      class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
        has_many :todo_lists, dependent: :destroy
        has_many :todo_items, through: :todo_lists, source: :todo_items
      end
```

There are other people that experienced the same problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392659/rails-console-is-adding-nil-instead-of-values) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123665/rails-rake-dbseed-inserts-nulls-instead-of-values) but I don't think that the solutions apply to my case as I do not have any attr_accessor in any of my models.

Anyone knows why that might be happening?

Comment: brace-types matter... use `User.create!( username: "test", password_digest: "test" )` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

brace-types matter...

use the following instead

```
User.create!( username: "test", password_digest: "test" )
```

This tells rails to create a single user, using the hash that contains username "test" and password "test"

what you have is telling rails to create a user with an array `[]` that contains a hash `{}`... but create is not expecting an array of hashes - it's expecting just a single hash.

EDIT: re: using `[]`

That's because when you don't use `()` but do use `[]`, then ruby has to guess what you mean... 
are you passing an array to a method or are you calling the array-indexing method on a variable? (or hash-indexing if it's not an integer in the brackets)?

If you put the `[]` right next to the word `create!` (eg `User.create![]`) ruby will probably interpret that as the latter... eg it's looking for an variable on the `User` class called `create!`... and then tries to look for a key of that hash called `{username: "test", password_digest: "test"}, {username: "test2", password_digest: "test2"}` and then it gets confused because when you use the array-indexing method `[]` you should pass it only one key to find, not two (`{username: "test", password_digest: "test"}` is the first and `{username: "test2", password_digest: "test2"}` is the second)... thus giving you the error that you're trying ot pass 2 arguments instead of one... but also just using the wrong interpretation to begin with.

neither of which is what you want...

If you leave a space between the `[]` and `create!` then ruby is more likely to interpret the `[]` as a parameter being passed to a method... and then it triggers a different error.

To be unambiguous - always use a space... or use parens `()` when passing an argument that could be ambiguous in this way.

Comment: Thank you Taryn -  this is really helpful. Quick question - I got confused because in the course I am following we have an example where we create two users using the following code: 
User.create! [
  {username: "test", password_digest: "test"},
  {username: "test2", password_digest: "test2"}
]
and it works when there is a gap between the create! and the opening of the array but it gives me an error "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)" when there is not a gap. Would you know why?

Comment: I'll update my answer with this as it's too long to write here ;)

Comment: Cool. it's a bit complex, and requires an understanding of how ruby tries to figure out what you mean when you write your code...

Comment: that's a great explanation and now I get it 100% - thank you so much for taking the time to teach me :)